# How to add second value in the link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, get

I have:

```
<select name="user" id="user">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option>...</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#category').change(function(){
    var id_user = $('#user').val();
    var url = 'stock_fetch.php?id_cat=' + $(this).val();
    $('#frame').load(url);
});
</script>
```

Now works but I have to add in the link and `var id_user` to have something like this:

`http://www.example.com/stock_fetch.php?id_user=xxx&id_cat=xxx`

My idea is when choose `id_user` nothing happen but get the value and when choose the `id_cat` then load url with `id_user` and `id_cat` values in the link.

Comment: My mistake when post question, I don't paste that part of code. Updated.

Comment: Something like this? If you could specify the domain for replacing `example.com` then this fiddle could be more effective..: http://jsfiddle.net/mohitk117/8pzjzjdu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$('#category').change(function(){
    var id_user = $('#user').val();
    var id_cat = $(this).val();
    var url = 'stock_fetch.php?id_user=' + id_user + '&id_cat=' + id_cat;
    $('#frame').load('http://www.example.com/' + url);

    alert($('#frame').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$('#category,#user').change(function(){
    var id_user = $('#user').val();
    var id_category = $('#category').val();
    var url = 'stock_fetch.php?id_user='+id_user+'&id_cat='+id_category;
    if(id_user&&id_category){
       $('#frame').load(url);
    }
});
</script>
```